# Выборка с объединением и лимитом

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день Всем добра.

В общем есть 3 таблици. Нужно выбрать все значения, но ограничить выборку лимитом. Что бы значеня выбирались по 9 штук,по полю TEXT.id, **и вот тут я не пойму как это сделать**.

***поясняю по тому что не совсем корректно изложил вопрос.***

Нужно выбрать 9 записей не зависимо сколько находится значений в таблице SRC .

Например в таблице SRC 200 записей и в таблице TEXTS 20 записей.

Нужно выбрать все записи где SRC.event_id одинаковы, Но что выборка начиналась с  9 по 18 event_i.

[image: Вот как бы пример]

---

```
CREATE TABLE `SRC`(
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
`event_id` int(10) NOT NULL ,
`big_src` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
`small_src` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
`alternate` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES TEXTS(id)
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `TEXTS`(
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
`big_text` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
`small_text` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `ALL`(
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
`TEXT_id` int(10) NOT NULL ,
`SRC_event_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (TEXT_id) REFERENCES TEXTS(id),
FOREIGN KEY (SRC_event_id) REFERENCES SRC(event_id)
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

---

```
SELECT event_id,small_src,alternate,small_text,datetime FROM `TEXTS` 
INNER JOIN `SRC` ON `TEXTS`.id=`SRC`.event_id INNER JOIN `ALL` ON 
`TEXTS`.id=`ALL`.TEXT_id ;
```

Comment: limit? И при чём тут php?

Comment: поясняю по тому что не совсем корректно изложил вопрос. Нужно выбрать 9 записей не зависимо сколько находится  значений в таблице SRC . Например в таблице SRC 200 записей и в таблице TEXTS 20 записей. Нужно  выбрать все записи  где SRC.event_id одинаковы,  Но что  выборка начиналась с например с 9 по 18 event_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что Вы ищете что-то вроде:

```
SELECT t.id event_id,s.small_src,s.alternate,a.small_text,t.datetime 
FROM `TEXTS` t
JOIN `SRC` s ON s.event_id = t.id
JOIN `ALL` a ON a.TEXT_id = t.id
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT id FROM TEXTS ORDER BY id LIMIT 9 OFFSET 1*9)
```

Запрос постранично выбирает по 9 texts.id и связанные с ними данные. Страница выбирается параметром offset(0*9, 1*9, 2*9 и т.д.)
*Вероятно стоит применить left join, если данных связанных с некоторыми texts.id может не быть.*

---

> [42000][1235] This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

```
SELECT t.id event_id,s.small_src,s.alternate,a.small_text,t.datetime 
FROM `TEXTS` t
JOIN `SRC` s ON s.event_id = t.id
JOIN `ALL` a ON a.TEXT_id = t.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM TEXTS ORDER BY id LIMIT 9 OFFSET 1*9) t2
  ON t.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Да что то похожее на правду но пишет **[42000][1235] This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'**

Comment: Можно переписать через Join, секунду

Comment: Что то с умножением не то а так почти работает)

Comment: Ну, умножать лучше заранее... Т.е. передавать 0, 9, 18, 27... Также можно использовать синтаксис `LIMIT 27, 9`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT event_id,small_src,alternate,small_text,datetime 
FROM `TEXTS` 
INNER JOIN `SRC` ON `TEXTS`.id=`SRC`.event_id 
INNER JOIN `ALL` ON `TEXTS`.id=`ALL`.TEXT_id 
order by event_id
limit 9 OFFSET 9
```

limit 9 - сколько записей выводить

OFFSET 9 - сколько пропустить

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса.

Comment: Не совсем то, дело в том что мне нужно колличество event_id может быть как 3 так и 23 так и 100. А нужно выбрать только 9 event_id

Comment: **SELECT SRC.id,event_id,small_src,alternate,small_text,datetime FROM TEXTS INNER JOIN SRC ON TEXTS.id=SRC.event_id WHERE event_id = 1;**  Что бы каждый раз не подставлять вместо 1 другие числа.

Comment: Если вам нужен диапазон данных используйте WHERE event_id between значение_от and значение_до